# Nginx requires port 433 on URL

Tags: ssl, nginx

I'm trying to setup Nginx to work with SSL. When I visit the home page, the webserver tells me the page is not available. But when I add the port 433 on the URL, it just works. What should I do to not require the port 433 on the URL?

```
    server {
            ssl on;
            listen 433 ssl;
            ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-bundle.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/server.key;

            server_name mywebsite.com;
            access_log on;

            location / {
                    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8001;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard port for SSL is 443, not 433.